# How to use constant powers of 2 readable in c++?

Tags: c++, binary, coding-style, constants, code-readability

I need several integer constants with `2^n` and `2^n - 1` in my `GNU c++` code.

What is a good practise  to keep the code readable? The code uses decimal values at the moment 4294967296 and 65536 which is hard to debug in future.

`2^12` is not implemented in standard C++ and `pow(2.0,12.0)` uses `double`.

```
if (buffer_length == 4294967295){ } // code example, I want to make more readable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the shift left operator:

```
if (buffer_length == 1 << 12){ }
```

Comment: This solution is well readable. Can you imagine a better solution than `2 << 32 - 1` for `2^n-1` for the ...11111111 bit patterns?

Comment: This should be `1 << 12` (or `1U << 12`).

Comment: @Jonas: Why not `if (buffer_length + 1 == 1u << 12)` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt In my eyes the code should represent the problem where it is possible. That will make it less error prone and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use hex. It should be pretty easy for anyone to figure out that it's a special number.

Comment: @JonasStein You're mixing up hex and binary.

Comment: hex is not so easy to read with human eyes: `2^64 = 0x10000000000000000` and `2^64-1 = 0xffffffffffffffff`
One has to count the number of f and 0 which is error prone and difficult to read.

Comment: @JonasStein then do what everyone else does and give the constants names and use those instead of having magic numbers all over.